# Why Shape.Width is sometimes Integer and sometimes Decimal?

Tags: vba

I would like to ask, why sometimes when I use the following code on a selected textbox, I will get the msgbox return value in multiple decimals places (eg. 3-6 decimals place) and sometimes it will return a whole number with the same textbox

```
Sub getShapeNow()

With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

MsgBox .Name
MsgBox .Width
MsgBox .Height
MsgBox .Top
MsgBox .Left

End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Powerpoint` obviously does not support any Width, but only some Width, which is based on the screen rezolution. Thus, if you try

```
Sub GetShapeNow()

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        .Width = 47.00147
        Debug.Print .Width
    End With

End Sub
```

I would see `47.0015` printed on the immediate window,as a `Width` as exact as `.00147` is not supported by my rezolution.

---

The properties are a decimal with values after the comma. If there are no values after the comma, e.g. `47` and not `47.01`, the `VBA` writes the value as `47`.

Check this:

```
Sub GetShapeNow()

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        .Width = 47
        .Height = 34
        .Top = 40.4
        .Left = 147
        Debug.Print .Name; .Width; .Height; .Top; .Left
    End With  

End Sub
```

At the immediate window you see this:

```
Rectangle 1 47  34  40,4  147
```

In general, the value that `Shape.Width` returns is from type `Single`:

- [MSDN Shape.Width Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-width-property-excel)
- [Single Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/single-data-type)

Comment: Thanks Vityata for your reply. My queries is sometimes I found a textbox to return a value like 47.00147, but sometimes when I use .width it will return me a whole number like 47. isit possible to return a long value instead of single ?

Comment: @GeraldTow - "I found a textbox to return a value like 47.00147"... what do you mean?

Comment: Hi Vityata, Thanks for your response. what I mean, I tried used msgbox .width on a textbox in a slide, it will return value with 47.00147. then I closed the file. someday in another week, I opened the same file and use .width on the same textbox, it might return only whole number. Hope this clarify

Comment: @GeraldTow - I see. I guess it is a problem of the rezolution. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Vityata for your clarification